# Retrieve data using axios and append data to elements created in callback function

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to use axios to retrieve data from a url and then append the data to html elements I created using javascript.

In a nutshell for each programming language in my url I would like to have a card showing the headline and author name of each article.

This is my HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="parentDiv">
    
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and my JS

```
const CardsTest = (one) => {
  // class headline
  const divHead = Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), {className: 'one', textContent: one.headline});
  // class author
  const divAut = Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), {className: 'writer'});
  const spanCont = Object.assign(document.createElement('span'), {className: 'name', textContent: one.authorName});
  divAut.appendChild(SpanCont);
  divHead.appendChild(divAut);
  return divHead;
}

 const cardAppender = (div) => {
    const divOne = document.querySelector(div);
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/articles')
      .then((resp) => {
        Object.keys(resp.data).forEach (
          function(obj) {
            const topicsData = CardsTest(obj.articles);
            divOne.appendChild(obj.articles)
          }
        )
      })
  }
 
 cardAppender('parentDiv')
```

I know that my function CardsTest creates all the components and my cardsappender can, at the very least print out the JSON from the target URL. I know if I run the function with axios and console log `obj.articles` I get an object promise containing the articles in the URL.

To summarize; I expect cardAppender to take a url, and take a callback function (Cards Test) appending the writer and headline to the elements in Cards Test and then append that to my html parentDiv. However this is not happening

**UPDATE**

Tried changing my cardAppender function by creating an array of programming languages (the keys in my JSON) and then appending headline and authorname for each article to my Cards Test function, but this function is still not creating the components in Cards Test:

```
const cardsAppender = (div) => {
  const newArr = ["javascript","bootstrap","technology","jquery","node"]
const divOne = document.querySelector('.parentDiv');
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/articles')
      .then((resp) => {
      newArr.forEach((item) => {
        const cardsHolds = CardsTest(resp.data.articles[item])
        divOne.appendChild(cardsHolds)
      })
  })
}
cardsAppender('.parentDiv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Object.keys` to iterate, so you need to use that key as a property index.  Or use `Object.values`.  It's not really clear what shape your data is though, so this might need to be tweaked.

```js
Object.keys(resp.data).forEach (
          function(obj) {
            const topicsData = CardsTest(res.data[obj].articles);
            divOne.appendChild(res.data[obj].articles)
          }

Object.values(resp.data).forEach (
          function(obj) {
            const topicsData = CardsTest(obj.articles);
            divOne.appendChild(obj.articles)
          }
```